# Is there any way to get Katrina's (fortune teller) flooring in ACNL?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I need her flooring for a witchy-themed house in ACNL. I've seen people on the internet having her flooring in their homes (carpet with circular star wheel and what looks like runes) and I really want to know if it is hacked or if I can get it in the game.